# The electron render processes get unresponsive when a heavy task runs in the main process

Tags: electron

We are using electron framework. I believe we need to keep the main process non blocking at all times, If I run the slightest of heavy operation in it the render process get unresponsive. To counter it we are thinking of keeping only windowing code in the main process and fork a process out with the main business logic in it. That main process would accept requests from the render context and use the forked process to do the code. This way the UI of the app would never feel non-responsive. Is there a better way around this. This approach seems to be an abuse of the division of labor gained by fork.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you shouldn't block the main process, it needs to be able to communicate with the renderer process(es). Moving work to a separate process (either a plain Node child process, or a hidden browser window) is the recommended approach to deal with this.